# Laravel: Gate::denies not working

Tags: php, authorization, laravel-5.1

So I am trying to use Laravel `Authorization`. For [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.11) I did following:

- Laravel updated to *.1.19
- Create The Policies Directory
- Facade defined in app.php

I created a Policy and put following code in it:

```
//Allow users of type 'users`    
public function view(User $user)
        {
            dd('he was here'); // Not coming here
            return $user->user_type === 'user';
        }
```

In Controller I did:

```
if (Gate::denies('view')) {
            dd('Sorry Bud not allowed');
        }
```

Thing is, it is always getting into blocks `'Sorry Bud not allowed'`.

Am I missing some step or something else?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am stuck on the same thing.

Comment: @Shane I skipped this

Comment: @Shane I am stucked at the same thing. Did you manage to get it work?

Comment: Check if you are using php-cs and it corrects name spaces to "app\.." instead of "App\..."

Comment: Never got this to work

Answer (score 2):

this is just because you not log in to your project to know the user.
so first log in to your project then this code is work.

Comment: Can you explain this better please?

Comment: this is logically incorrect . because if you don't login to the project how laravel could know your role

Answer (score 1):

2 things to check with Gate

First: Make sure your policy is getting registered.

Second: If you have setup custom Guard in config.auth in that case inside your controller add the below line.

```
config(['auth.defaults.guard','YOUR-CUSTOM-GUARD-NAME']);
```

Thanks
[Mage2 Ecommerce](http://mage2.website/)

Comment: Yes, that Guard must seting if You use 2 guard. see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12087

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register your policies, see Registering Policies section in the documentation
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#policies

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to add `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,` to the providers array in config/app.php.